# how to prepare a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

my adsl has a couple of numeric variables, and I want to summarize them to get a summarize dataset. Below is my code and I take AGE and STAGEN variables as examples:

```
adsl <- adsl %>% group_by(ACTARM)

AGE <- summarise(adsl,
    param='AGE',
    mean=mean(AGE, na.rm = TRUE),
    sd = sd(AGE, na.rm = TRUE),
    median = quantile(AGE, probs = 0.5),
    min = min(AGE),
    max = max(AGE)
  )
STAGEN <- summarise(adsl,
                    param='STAGEN',
                    mean=mean(STAGEN, na.rm = TRUE),
                    sd = sd(STAGEN, na.rm = TRUE),
                    median = quantile(STAGEN, probs = 0.5),
                    min = min(STAGEN),
                    max = max(STAGEN)
)
result <- rbind(AGE, STAGEN)
```

My question is how can I write a for loop to replace the repeated code

```r
for (i in c('AGE', 'STAGEN')){
  i <- adsl %>% 
    summarise(
      param=i,
      mean=mean(adsl[i], na.rm = TRUE),
      sd = sd(adsl[i], na.rm = TRUE),
      median = quantile(adsl[i], probs = 0.5),
      min = min(adsl[i]),
      max = max(adsl[i])
    )
}
```

I hope someone can help me out

Comment: It's not clear what the end-result should be, nor do we have sample data to see what's going on. We _might_ be able to fake it, but having sample data really makes it clearer. Please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(adsl,20))` (or some other row-selection/sampling method), ensuring that we see enough of at least one group to be able to demonstrate what you need.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You have not supplied an extract of your data, but perhaps the following will give you enough of an idea. This is a base R solution, so you should be able to adjust it for `dplyr` if you need. First some sample data:

```
set.seed(124L)
adsl <- data.frame(ID = as.character(1:1000),
                   AGE = runif(1000L, 0, 10),
                   STAGEN = rnorm(1000L, 10, 2))
```

The idea will be to write a function which, when passed a parameter list, will identify which columns to extract, remove `NA`s if that is desired, and then populate the desired statistics. In modern versions of R, loops are of the same order of magnitude speed as `apply` functions; using them no longer has the time penalty they had back in R 1+ and 2+ days.

```
sumsum <- function(x, paramlist, na.rm = TRUE) {
  n <- length(paramlist)
  # preallocate your output if you can. Matrices are the most efficient tabular
  # form in R. Since all our output is numeric, we can use them.
  ret <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = 5L)
  rownames(ret) <- paramlist
  colnames(ret) <- c("mean", "sd", "median", "min", "max")
  # Key loop
  for (i in seq_along(paramlist)) {
    # Extract the column from the data frame.
    # Use tolower to avoid capitalization issues.
    data <- x[, which(tolower(colnames(x)) == tolower(paramlist[i]))]
    # Make NA treatment consistent across ALL parameters
    if (na.rm) data <- data[!is.na(data)]
    # Populate the approriate row with the data we need.
    ret[i, ] <- c(mean(data), sd(data), quantile(data, probs = 0.5),
                  min(data), max(data))
  }
  # Use R's implicit return of last called operation.
  ret
}
```

Results

```
> paramlist <- c("STAGEN", "AGE")
> sumsum(adsl, paramlist)
           mean       sd   median        min       max
STAGEN 9.938689 2.042672 9.938728 4.12627067 15.631314
AGE    4.915760 2.816910 4.821304 0.00245204  9.978901
```